# Booting Computer on Drive With Windows Shows GRUB Menu, Want to Remove the Menu & Boot Ubuntu From BIOS Disk Selection

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have Windows 7 (my primary OS) installed on my SSD, and I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 (I only use it occasionally) on a partition I made of my HDD which I also use to store files on.

My BIOS is set to start my SSD by default. Whenever I boot, I see the GRUB menu asking for which OS to boot (Windows 7 or Ubuntu and other recovery versions of Ubuntu).

I want Windows 7 to boot automatically, and never show GRUB menu again. I want to be able to boot Ubuntu when I need it from my BIOS by selecting my HDD or the partition I made for Ubuntu from the boot disk selection menu in my BIOS.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know which disk `Grub` is installed onto? To check, run the [BootInfoScript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and show us the output. I'm assuming `Grub` is installed on your SSD's `MBR`. The idea is to remove it from there, and install it on your HDD's `MBR`. You'll need a `LiveDVD/LiveUSB` session to do either. More importantly, you'll need to ensure that `Windows` doesn't need `Grub` to boot before removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the bootloader of Windows, because windows always overwrites existing bootloaders.

Comment: How will he boot into Ubuntu then?

Comment: he can use the BIOS menu (like he wrote in his question)

Comment: I think that although the Linux filesystem is installed on the other disk, `Grub` is installed on the main disk (his `SSD`). Overwriting it with the Windows bootloader is a little redundant, and he won't be able to boot into Ubuntu. Might as well move `Grub` to the second disk (`HDD`). Less messy.